# SQL to calculate values between a range of numbers using case

Tags: sql, postgresql

With this simple CASE statement

```
SELECT 
    title, length, 
    CASE length
       WHEN '4:00' THEN 'LONG' 
       WHEN '1:00' THEN 'SHORT' 
       ELSE 'MIDDLE' 
    END media 
FROM
    general;
```

Output:

```
          title            | length | media
---------------------------+--------+-------------
 My song number 1          | 4:00   | LONG
 My song number 2          | 2:30   | MIDDLE
 My song number 3          | 3:10   | MIDDLE
 My song number 4          | 4:23   | MIDDLE
```

It return correctly the values is the value is the correct value(for example 4:00 = long), how to do for a average media?

For example between 1:00 and 2:00 is short, between 2:00-3:00 is middle, over 3:00 is long?

I have tried using 'between 1:30 and 1:44' but I have no success.

I have also tried with

```
 SELECT
     title, length, 
     CASE length 
        WHEN > '4:00' THEN 'LONG' 
        WHEN < '1:00' THEN 'SHORT' 
        ELSE 'MIDDLE' 
     END media 
 FROM 
     general;
```

But I get a syntax error.

DB is Postgresql, datatype of length is integer

Comment: datatype of the length column?

Comment: Integer, I add  now to description

Comment: **TYPO** alert - it's spelled **length** ("th" at the end) - not "lenght" ....

Comment: `length` cannot be an integer if it contains `4:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the below query

```
select title,lenght, 
CASE  
when general.length BETWEEN 1:00 AND 2:00 THEN 'SHORT'
when general.length BETWEEN 2:00 AND 3:00 THEN 'MIDDLE'
else 'LONG' 
end media 
from general;
```

Comment: Is perfect only the values must be enclosed in ' ' in my case because "general" is a view

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the logic that you really want is:

```
select title, length, 
       (case when g.length < '2:00' then 'SHORT'
             when g.length < '3:00' then 'MIDDLE'
             else 'LONG'
        end) as media 
from general g;
```

Notes:

- `BETWEEN` includes the end-points. If you use `BETWEEN '1:00' and '2:00'` then `2:00` is considered "SHORT".
- `BETWEEN` is unnecessary because `CASE` expressions are evaluated in order.  That is guaranteed.
- If length is less than `'1:00'`, then I am guessing that "SHORT" is a better category than "LONG".
- If `length` is `NULL`, then this (and all other solutions) will categorize that as `LONG`.
- Because you are using strings, this will not work for values of `10:00` and greater.